# Click the second image with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, click, casperjs

There are 2 Imagebuttons on my website looking like this:

```
<img class="img" src="img.png" alt="Image">
<img class="img" src="img.png" alt="Image">
```

This is my code:

```
this.click('img[src="img.png"]');
```

This code will click only the first button.

But how is it possible to click only the second button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with XPath:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
...
this.click(x('(//img[@src="img.png"])[2]'));
```

Explanation:

- `//` "searches" on every descendant node from the root
- `img[@src="img.png"]` matches the img (both of your images)
- `(nodelist)[2]` takes the second result of the `nodelist`

The crucial part is the last point, because CSS selectors don't have that operator in a general way, but they have something similar.

If the images have the same parent and there are no other images under the same parent, then you can do:

```
this.click('img[src="img.png"]:nth-child(2)');
```